# Where are these borders in Flutter App coming from and how do I set it right?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set the colors of my App in a theme file to avoid repeating code in every widget I define, but I'm having issues where I do not know where the border from some widgets come from. I have a custom AppBar that has a white line at the beginning and the end (see picture) and I do not know how to remove it, or where to put the same color of the bar, so it does not show.

[image]

The bar code is as follow:

```
  return TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.textFieldBorderColor),
        ),
        hintText: 'Search',
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
        iconColor: Colors.black),
  );
}
```

This is the theme code for dark mode:

```
class ThemeDark {
  static ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
      background: Color.fromARGB(255, 23, 22, 22),
      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 13, 13),
      secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 32, 32),
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
      // enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.textFieldBorderColor),
      // ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.textFieldBorderColor),
      ),
    ),
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        side: BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.borderSideBottonColor),
        foregroundColor: ColorConstants.buttonTextColor,
        backgroundColor: ColorConstants.bottomMenuBackgroundColor,
        elevation: 10,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I commented the enabledBorder parameter because in my login page when is uncommented the border appears in black instead of white, as if it were taking the color from the dark theme default colors. These textfiels are TextFormField widget inside the Form widget.

[image]

Where are these borders in Flutter App coming from and how do I set it right using the theme dart file?

Comment: What is the value of the `ColorConstants.textFieldBorderColor`?

Comment: The value is Colors.white